# Python code to run bash commands in Windows

Tags: python, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am making a simple code to automate my tedious task. I have installed ubuntu in wsl. I have used tkinter, and used a button to execute few commands in bash.

```
os.chdir(root.destiny)
bash = 'blockMesh'
pipefile = open('output', 'w')
retcode = call(bash, shell=True, stdout=pipefile)
pipefile.close()
os.remove('output')
os.chdir("..")
```

Below is the error that i am facing:
('blockMesh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)

Elaborating:
I am trying to create a mesh, changes is made using editing files in one of the folder. I need to run the a command in that particular folder 'blockMesh' which will run few codes to create a mesh.

Can someone help me with the same. I tried making 'bash' to 'cmd' in the code but didn't work.
Need a helping hand.

Thanks

Comment: "unable to run" is a bad problem description. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, try to solve this one thing in isolation, then you also have the mandatory [mcve] for your question here. BTW: It's unclear in what system you're running your code. The correct way might depend on that.

Comment: over here my 'bash code' is 'blockMesh'. I am using pycharm, python 3.10. The error i am facing is ('blockMesh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

Comment: bash is a shell that does not run on windows except under WSL ... batch is the shell language of cmd.exe

Comment: So there isn't any way i can run the bash command in windows using python? I have already installed WSL. I can open bash from start program.

Comment: Add all that info to your question, you can [edit] it! BTW, there are bash ports to MS Windows, you don't need WSL for it. However, I'd first look at the actual goal rather than focusing on a specific tool.

Comment: hi @UlrichEckhardt I have elaborated and mentioned error that i am facing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for editing - It's much more clear now.  Take a look at [Passing Commands to the WSL Shell from a Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239268/passing-commands-to-the-wsl-shell-from-a-python-script).  I believe it will demonstrate the right method for this.  You'll need to call WSL Bash scripts in Windows Python *through*/using the `wsl.exe` command.

Comment: thanks @NotTheDr01ds, i can use 'ls' commands but it did not execute 'blockMesh' command. It is not throwing error but '1' as an output. I have tried with 'runApplication blockMesh' but same output '1'. I do not see any changes made by executing the command which it should make. Also if i have a file named 'execute' in the same folder containing commands such as 'blockMesh', how do i execute that file?

Comment: @Jigs `blockMesh` is part of OpenFOAM, right?  IIRC, OpenFOAM modifies your Bash profile or rc startup, in which case you'll need to use the `bash -lic` form instead of `sh -c` to launch it.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048183/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-command-via-wsl-command-and-opening) for the reason why.  If that doesn't fix it, we'll probably need more debugging details, but start with editing the question to include the code that's been updated with what you've tried now.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is part of OpenFoam, you are correct. Thanks for help. I will look into it and let you know. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Dude @NotTheDr01ds , i bow down to you, it worked perfectly the way i wanted! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jigs Good to hear that worked!  You're welcome!