# How to use python to write wsl shell command?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I now python can be used to write windows cmd by import os and use os.popen(), and it can also write linux shell. But now I need to run python on my windows system, and there's a wsl2 on this windows system. How can I use python in the windows host to control this wsl ubuntu system ?
I can input 'wsl' in windows cmd, and then input linux shell command in wsl,such as:

```
windows cmd>wsl
wsl shell>cd ..
wsl shell>ls
```

but if I use python to run these commands by os.popen(), it doesn't show any result!

Comment: If you run the python script within the wsl shell then os.popen should use wsl directly.  Is there a reason you want to run the script directly in Windows but still use wsl?

Comment: This should be what you are looking for - [Passing Commands to the WSL Shell from a Windows Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239268/passing-commands-to-the-wsl-shell-from-a-windows-python-script).  Funny that it's the second time inside a week that this has come up (the other one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72864395/11810933)).  The trick is essentially to use the `wsl.exe -e <shell> -c <commands>` form.

Comment: @sturgemeister thanks for ur reply. The reason why I wanna run python script in Windows is I need to write a GUI on windows for others' use. And then some of the functions must run in Linux so I choose wsl.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thx a lot man! I tried it and it works!